# the move from Primary market to secondary mark

Tags: stocks, ipo

i do understand both markets and the mechanism of them
but i don't understand how works the first time the stocks get to the secondary market 
who is the one that sells? the guy that just bought in the IPO (a day +- ago) 
where does the flow of stocks come to the market?
thanks allot

Answer (score 4):

After an IPO, the shares are listed on the exchange for trading. The individual who just bought the IPO a few days ago, the Original owners who may want to sell some more, the other Institutional investors etc ... in short all the owners[shareholders] of the company who want to sell, will sell in the secondary market.

Some shares of the owners may not be vested and they cannot sell. At times owners will not sell beyoned a percentage as they may loose control of the company. Otherwise in theory every other share can be sold into the secondary market provided the current owners get the price they feel is right and there are buyers to pay that price.